# Is there a way to compare two lists of known equal size functionally with a given comparison function in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, functional-programming, comparison

I am trying to compare two arrays of known equal size and compare items by index. Normally the following code is what I would use to achieve this:

```
public bool CompareLists(object[] arr1, object[] arr2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (!( <compare arr1[i] to arr2[i]; may not be equality comparison> ))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Is there a way to do this functionally in C#? What about using Linq? I am trying to see if something like the following is possible:

```
return arr.Compare(arr2, (item1, item2) => < some comparison here > );
```

Comment: You can use Linq's [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342073%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which lets you pass in a predicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342073(v=vs.100).aspx). You can provide it an `IEqualityComparer`. Example from MSDN:

```
Product[] storeA = { new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                           new Product { Name = "orange", Code = 4 } };

Product[] storeB = { new Product { Name = "apple", Code = 9 }, 
                           new Product { Name = "orange", Code = 4 } };

bool equalAB = storeA.SequenceEqual(storeB, new ProductComparer());

Console.WriteLine("Equal? " + equalAB);
```

If you want to avoid creating a class that implements `IEqualityComparer` for each comparison, you'll have to create your own overload of the `SequenceEqual` method.

Comment: Almost what I'm looking for. I may not be checking for equality, though. And I would also have to implement an `IEqualityComparer` for each comparison I want to do on the two lists, right? This is cumbersome if I want to do multiple types of comparisons.

Comment: Using a comparer doesn't force you to check for equality, you can compare on whatever values you want. You are correct, though, that you'll have to implement an `IEqualityComparer` for each comparison. I think this might be the closest you get with a framework method, though... You might have to implement your own.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for adding my own. I wound up just doing that. If you add that suggestion to your answer I will accept it. :)